# The relation between throughput, SNR and bits per channel use

Tags: snr

Typically when describing a new scheme of modulation we see how many bits can be encoded on a particular symbol. This is dependent on the size of the constellation in the complex plane and we say

$$
b = \log_2(M) 
$$

where $M$ is constellation size and $b$ is the throughput.

- So how is this throughput affected by SNR?
- How does channel capacity factor into this?

Comment: $b$ is not the throughput; it's just the number of bits per constellation point.

Answer (score 1):

The constant $b$ in the equation has nothing to do with throughput. It is just the number of bits per symbol if there are $M$ symbols. This is just the transmitter side, so there is no channel involved. You can only talk about throughput if there is a channel. If your *symbol* rate is $1/T$ and if you had an ideal channel (no distortion, no noise), then your throughput (i.e., the number of bits per second) would be $b/T$. Of course, in practice this won't happen.

The channel capacity tells you the maximum information rate that can be reliably transmitted over a given channel. Note that the channel capacity is independent of your choice of $M$ or $b$.

Comment: So if I need to calculate the throughput at the receiver given b bits per symbol at the transmitter how would I do it ( considering over a range of SNR)

Comment: @PSK: You can *calculate* the channel capacity, and you can *measure* the throughput of an actual system. The actual throughput (which of the many definitions do you mean?) depends on lots of factors. Channel capacity and throughput will not only depend on the SNR but also on the channel bandwidth.

Comment: To stress what Matt said: the info you have given is not enough to calculate *throughput*. *Throughput* is a performance aspect of a communication *system*, and constellation size is just one of **a lot** of aspects of such a system.